# What platforms do Google Protocol Buffers support?

Tags: protocol-buffers

Google state that:

> Protocol buffers are Google's language-neutral, platform-neutral, extensible mechanism for serializing structured data

I searched for an explicit list of platforms and/or operating systems officially supported by Protocol Buffers but I couldn't find it. Ironically the closest thing I found was the following information in the Wikipedia page:

- Operating system: Any
- Platforms: Cross-platform

Is it safe to say that Protocol Buffers support any platform/OS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Operating system is going to be any *mainstream* OS. If you're running something esoteric, you might get the same problems that you get with anything else.

Platform is similar; google offer support for a range of platforms, and a much wider list is provided by community owned projects. A list is here: https://github.com/google/protobuf/blob/master/docs/third_party.md

Ultimately, the wire specification is documented and doesn't depend on OS or platform, so worst case if you're using a custom language on a custom OS, then you could still implement your own decoder *as long as* that language has some mechanism to talk arbitrary binary data *or* can interop to one of the other prebuilt libraries.